# user input args value to remove from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

when user runs `script.py -r sampletext` I want this to remove that text from the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import shutil
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.r:
        f = open("config.dat","r")
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
```

What I'm trying to do here is after the above code has read the file then the code below will re-write the file and leave out the `args` command :

```
f = open("config.dat","w")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    if line!= (args.r + "\n"): #Replace this string with your arg var
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `action="store_true"`, that means that `args.r` will be stored as a boolean (True/False).
If you want ro retrieve the argument after the `-r` option you have to use:

```
parser.add_argument('-r', dest='to_remove')
```

Then you can access it with `args.to_remove`.

Please read more about the [add_argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) method.